# Does an mdadm RAID 1 get checked automatically, or do I need to schedule a weekly check?

Tags: raid, mdadm

I have mdadm setup to email on the event of it detecting an error on the RAID 1 array I have.

What I cannot find anywhere is if I need to schedule a check to run weekly, or if mdadm will automatically pick up that a drive is failing and notify me.

Has anyone experience with this or can point me in the correct direction?

I also have another RAID 5 array that I could ask the same question about.

Comment: What's there to check in RAID1? There are no parity bits.

Comment: Say if a drive starts failing to write? Or if it won't spin up?

Answer (score 6):

Speaking for at least mdadm RAID-5 arrays, a recheck gets scheduled for the first Sunday of every month.  You can do `sudo systemctl list-timers mdcheck_start` to confirm that it is scheduled to launch.

Comment: Ok, on the raid1 all I see is https://i.ibb.co/sJFhV60/image.png

Comment: Yep, `mdadm` is on the job and you shouldn't have to manually do anything.

Comment: Thanks for this! Obviously the command I was looking for. I checked the RAID5 and it's the same.